# NGINX Redirect to HTTPS only works after refresh

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, configuration

I want traffic to go to https://example.com. **No www prefix** is allowed and **SSL is required**.

The problem we are experiencing is that many (though not all) first time visitors are not being redirected to HTTPS until they hit refresh.

Do you see anything in my config that would allow this behavior?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name www.example.com;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/html/mm;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";

    client_max_body_size 200m;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        index index.php index.html index.htm install.php;
        client_max_body_size 200m;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        fastcgi_pass   php-fpm;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 150M \n upload_max_filesize=151M";
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "post_max_size = 150M \n post_max_size=151M";
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: You never redirect http -> https if people enter without `www.`. After refresh it works because of the HSTS header.

Comment: In the first block, `return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;` is the redirect.

Comment: Yes that is if people enter *with* `www.`

Comment: Please add an answer with the correct config and if it works I'll give you the credit.

Comment: Not sure if it will be helpful for future readers, because it basically boils down to "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."

Comment: It wasn't a typo, it was caused by poor logic, not handling both www and no-www traffic in my redirect. Based on the half dozen answers I read on S.O. about nginx https redirects I imagine others unknowingly have this bug in their configs too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @PeeHaa mentioned, you are missing a redirect from http to https for www.example.com. Try this where I've rearranged the server blocks a bit to add an HSTS header to the www server and to address a potential security misconfig where `http://www` is directly redirected to `https://(notwww)` (per https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Guidelines/Web_Security#HTTP_Redirections):

```
# HTTP server (non-www) -- redirect to https://example.com
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

# HTTP server (www) -- redirect to https://www.example.com
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS server (www) -- redirect to https://example.com -- Add HSTS header
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS server (non-www)
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/html/mm;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";

    client_max_body_size 200m;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        index index.php index.html index.htm install.php;
        client_max_body_size 200m;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        fastcgi_pass   php-fpm;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 150M \n upload_max_filesize=151M";
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "post_max_size = 150M \n post_max_size=151M";
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```